# UglifyJS2 invalid assignment on [] =

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I've started working on a old project which is using [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) to minify it's JS, but I get the following error when I run the gulp task:

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Invalid assignment
File: app/assets/js/main.js
Line: 92
invalid assignment [] =
```

Sure enogh when I look at line 92, I see a strange variable assignment which has a syntax I'm unfamiliar with:

```
[newTitle, newVal] = $('#' + elementId + '-title').text().replace('*', '').split(':');
```

It later occurs with:

```
[prodW = 0, prodL = 0, boxL = 0] = currentOption.text().split(/[\/-]/);
```

If I commnet out these lines I get more errors as `newTitle`, `newVal`, `prodW`, `prodL`, `boxL` are all used elsewhere.

**Any idea what's going on here is there a way to avoid these errors?**

Here is the **gulp task** I'm running in case it helps...

```
gulp.task('compressJS', function (cb) { 
    pump([
            gulp.src('app/assets/js/*.js'),
            uglify(),
            gulp.dest('build/js/')
        ],
        cb
    );
});
```

Comment: use a es6 capable uglifier or a transpiler to create es5 code first, then uglify that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of JavaScript ES6, called [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

The problem is that `Uglify2` is not ES6 compatible. You can either try to use the new `Uglify3`, which is compatible, or transform your ES6 code to ES5 first, with something like `gulp-babel`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel

The advantage of doing it with Babel is also that older browsers do not support ES6.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, that makes sense. So I tried converting back to es5 with [bable online](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=NoOwpg7gKglgLgGzAGgATggNQIYILqoC8qAJABQDkAxBagNSphIC2YIcAkgCb2oUC0ceEgoBKAHRwwADzhkJAJzAAHBNgDGYSgCoKaCmPEBnVfEoAuMQG4gA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=&targets=&version=6.26.0), but nothing changes.  Do I need to select es2015 as one of the presets?

Comment: also do you know why babel adds an empty declaration at the end, `_currentOption$text$s;` ?

Comment: Yes, you need to set a preset. I'd recommend using the `env` preset, where you can supply a list of browsers that should be supported. But simply using `es2015` will work, too.

Comment: The declarations are just stuff that babel needs to transform the code. if they are really unused, Uglify will remove them for you. :)